# Looping over items in an array returns the whole array instead of an items

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, axios

I'm looping over an array with 2 items, where it should be giving me one item in the loop. However it just gives the entire array after looping.

```
[
  {
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      date: 'Fri, 17 Mar 2023 00:45:58 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close',
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
      'x-ratelimit-bucket': 'f7ead6a7674e5a323d93786263b66cb1',
      'x-ratelimit-limit': '50',
      'x-ratelimit-remaining': '49',
      'x-ratelimit-reset': '1679013958.858',
      'x-ratelimit-reset-after': '0.019',
      via: '1.1 google',
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400',
      'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
      'report-to': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=xKTf0hVCUg0G348XsfiUpPVF2S%2FRtHec4bcEjhc2ZHidVhzQ%2F8aZz1Gxu6IOlbC925BGHbB3cLCMHWyYyW4fOq9qmEdBHP3OVkm0kiQEyNOvtaoP%2BfslLDUdLgrn"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
      nel: '{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      server: 'cloudflare',
      'cf-ray': '7a91375a5ce4ad33-ATL'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      baseURL: 'https://discord.com/api/v10',
      method: 'get',
      url: '/channels/1071951518946828429',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /api/v10/channels/1071951518946828429 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bot +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.3.4\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: discord.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/v10/channels/1071951518946828429',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'discord.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: {
      id: '1071951518946828429',
      last_message_id: '1086060000423706675',
      type: 0,
      name: 'free-games',
      position: 18,
      flags: 0,
      parent_id: '753760260266655826',
      topic: null,
      guild_id: '753760255900516402',
      permission_overwrites: [Array],
      rate_limit_per_user: 0,
      nsfw: false
    }
  },
  {
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      date: 'Fri, 17 Mar 2023 00:45:59 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close',
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
      'x-ratelimit-bucket': 'f7ead6a7674e5a323d93786263b66cb1',
      'x-ratelimit-limit': '50',
      'x-ratelimit-remaining': '49',
      'x-ratelimit-reset': '1679013959.102',
      'x-ratelimit-reset-after': '0.019',
      via: '1.1 google',
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400',
      'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
      'report-to': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=%2BMv3IziW0ZzOch3ojFNTbd1MUrjAlXAQZoWuHmCbSPqVYGNB3h2Rt%2Fdc7z1B%2BIpSk%2BQOJkE0j%2By%2BXHZFjD4PejweFa4ywleT1aZdbKRe%2B4PlZGa7yhU98697pOH0"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
      nel: '{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      server: 'cloudflare',
      'cf-ray': '7a91375beb58b032-ATL'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      baseURL: 'https://discord.com/api/v10',
      method: 'get',
      url: '/channels/1071972385831526420',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /api/v10/channels/1071972385831526420 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bot +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.3.4\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: discord.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/v10/channels/1071972385831526420',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'discord.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: {
      id: '1071972385831526420',
      last_message_id: '1086060739615273091',
      type: 0,
      name: 'free-games',
      position: 32,
      flags: 0,
      parent_id: '983858995691405322',
      topic: null,
      guild_id: '983858506140639352',
      permission_overwrites: [Array],
      rate_limit_per_user: 0,
      nsfw: false
    }
  },
]
```

There are two items this array and I'm trying to loop over them using this code:

```
    /**
     * @param {Interaction[]} channels
     */
    async sendFreeGames(...channels) {
        const games = await this.#createEpicFreeGamesEmbeds();
        const buttons = await this.#createEpicFreeButtons();

        if (games.length === 0) return;

        for (const channel of channels) {
            // @ts-ignore
            const discordAxios = axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://discord.com/api/v10', headers: { Authorization: `Bot ${process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN}`,},});
            console.log(channel.data.type)
            discordAxios.post(`/channels/${channel.data.id}/messages`, { embeds: games, components: buttons });
        }
    }
}
```

However when looping and accessing `channel` it just returns the whole array instead of each item in the array leading to `channel.data.type`being undefined but `channel[0].data.type` being valid. I've been trying to solve this for 4 hours with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sendFreeGames(channels) {` instead of `sendFreeGames(...channels) {`. You are unnecessarily wrapping the array in another array here.

Comment: Andrew ... you should post your successful comment as an answer to be accepted. Credit where credit is due ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendFreeGames(channels)` instead of `sendFreeGames(...channels)`
the array was being wrapped in another array
| [solution by Đinh Carabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967864/%C4%90inh-carabus)